# Limit languages in cms

Tags: silverstripe

I use silverstripe 3.1
I would like to limit the languages (To only German and English) which are available in the drop down in the CMS. Therefore I put
the following code in my mysite/_config.php

```
i18n::set_locale('de_DE');
$allowed_locales = array(
   'de_DE' => array('Deutsch', 'Deutsch'),
   'en_EN' => array('English', 'English')
);
i18n::$common_locales = $allowed_locales;
```

Afer a flush=1 i get the following error: 
Fatal error: Cannot access private property i18n::$common_locales in ... _config.php

Any ideas what goes wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

as of 3.1 most of the static php variables are private. this means you can no longer access those.
the reason for this api change is that they are now cached by the config layer (this is also why you have to ?flush=1 now after changing private statics in classes like for example with `private static $db`)

if you want to update something in the config layer, you can do this with:

```
 Config::inst()->update('CLASS', 'FIELD', $value);
```

you could use use the config update to overwrite the common locales (class would be 'i18n', and field would be 'common_locales'):

```
Config::inst()->update('i18n', 'common_locales', $array);
```

**Note**: if you want to completely overwrite an existing configuration, you have to do a `remove()` first.

```
Config::inst()->remove('i18n', 'common_locales');
Config::inst()->update('i18n', 'common_locales', $array);
```

---

however, if you are using the translatable module and you want to limit the number of translatable languages, there is a much better way already built in:

```
// in your _config.php
i18n::set_locale('en_US');
Translatable::set_allowed_locales(array(
    'de_DE',
    'en_US',
 ));
```

Comment: When i use Translateable it means i have to use the translatable module from silverstripe.. By changing the language of the current user in the cms I use: Config::inst()->update('i18n', 'common_locales', $allowed_locales); No changes when i put this in _config.php after a flush=1 .. Could it be that my array above: $allowed_locales is wrong?

Comment: Ah I see, I assumed you where using Translateable, did not think of the field. And I missed a important detaul with config update, if you want to overwrite it, you have to remove the existing first. I'll update the answer

Comment: Unfortunately it not works for me if i call remove() function before the update() function. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thank you

Comment: Maybe there are problems with version 3.1?

Comment: This has worked perfectly for me in two instances: once when using Translatable to limit the languages in the CMS to en_US and fr_FR, then another time when trying to limit the languages displayed to users on a MemberProfilePage (in the latter case, the `remove` and `update` sequence using the Config API was the solution) from the 85 languages currently supported to the two languages I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Config it through YAML:

```
i18n:
  common_locales:
    nl_BE:
       name: Dutch (Belgium)
       native: Nederlands
    fr_BE:
      name: French (Belgium)
      native: Francais
```